# Hessian of the log barrier function is positive semidefinite

Tags: convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

How do I show that the hessian of the log barrier function is positive semi definite ? How do I show that $z^THz \ge 0$ for a non-zero z ? It looks extremely complicated. I forgot to mention that in the expression below, $f_i(x)$ is convex.

[image]

This is my attempt at a solution:

- $\triangledown f_i(x) \triangledown f_i(x)^T$ is positive semidefinite and $\dfrac{1}{f_i(x)^2}$ is just a positive multiplier. Thus the expression on the left is convex.
- $\triangledown^2 f_i(x)$ is non negative because it is the second derivative of a convex function. Since $f_i(x) $ must be $< 0$ (since it is used as a barrier for the inequality), then $\dfrac{1}{-f_i(x)}$ is positive.

Thus the expression is a sum of 2 positive semidefinite matrices, making it convex. Would this be correct ?

Comment: It is actually quite simple. Can you at least make a start?

Comment: @LinAlg I only know how to check if matrices are psd if I can explicitly expand out $z^THz$ and then look at the equation. I have no idea how to start here.

Comment: Do you know that if $A$ and $B$ are two positive semidefinite matrices then $A+B$ is also positive semidefinite? Similarly, $sA$ is positive semidefinite for any nonnegative scalar $s$? You can easily verify these facts using the $z^THz\ge0$ definition.

Comment: @Rahul okay i remember reading a proof that $\triangledown f(x) f(x)^T$ is positive semidefinite. But I am not sure about the second term because there is a negative and I dont know how to check if $\triangledown^2 f(x)$ is psd.

Comment: @LinAlg I have edited my post to add in my solution after reading some materials online. Could you help me check if it is correct ?

Comment: @kong congrats, you answered your own question! It all checks out. Be careful using convex for functions, positive semidefinite for matrices and nonnegative for scalars.

Comment: @LinAlg thank you !

Comment: You should post your solution as a self-answer. By the way, use `\nabla` ($\nabla$) instead of `\triangledown` ($\triangledown$) for the del operator.